# Using attribute STYLE in an element of XML document

Tags: xml, styles

I read that it is possible in a correct XML document to specify attribute STYLE to format output of an element.

So I defined an XML document the following way

```
//...some description is skipped

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="Inventory01.css"?>

<INVENTORY>

   <BOOK>
      <TITLE STYLE="font-style:normal;font-size:14pt">The Adventures of 

Huckleberry Finn</TITLE>
```

However when I try to open the document in MS IE 10 I do not see the effect of applying of the attribute STYLE. All elements are formatted according to specified CSS file "Inventory01.css".

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `style` attribute has a defined meaning in HTML documents. Browsers understand what the attribute means and what to do with it.

The `style` attribute doesn't have a defined meaning in your homebrewed XML format. Browsers don't understand what the attribute means.

Use a proper stylesheet.

Comment: However in book "Microsoft XML step by step" by Michael J.Young there is written that it can be used with XML elements as I showed.

Comment: I don't have a copy of that book, but it is either wrong or you are misinterpreting it. Maybe it is dealing with XML data islands or something?